# Is nginx affected by the log4j 0 day exploit found recently?

Tags: nginx, log4j

Trying to learn more about the recently discovered [0 day exploit](https://techcrunch.com/2021/12/13/the-race-is-on-to-patch-log4shell-as-attacks-begin-to-rise/)

This is a list of affected software I found -> https://github.com/NCSC-NL/log4shell/tree/main/software

It only says nginx in a note for F5.

If I am using an Ubuntu server with nginx to serve files over the internet, do I need to worry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nginx is not written in Java, it does not use log4j (which can only be used in applications written in Java), it is not vulnerable.